# How can I put a slider plugin in homepage using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to put image slider in my website homepage, so whenever a user clicks on the image, the user should redirected to my inner pages e.g refer [konsultapp](http://www.konsultapp.com/)

Please check my code below:-

';
            echo '';
                echo '';
                    echo '';
                        echo '';
                    echo '';
                echo '';
                echo '';

                    /*$sidebars_count = 0;  
                    for( $i = 1; $i  0 ){
                        switch( $sidebars_count ){
                            case 2: $sidebar_class = 'one-second'; break; 
                            case 3: $sidebar_class = 'one-third'; break; 
                            case 4: $sidebar_class = 'one-fourth'; break;
                            default: $sidebar_class = 'one';
                        }
                    }

                    for( $i = 1; $i ';
                                dynamic_sidebar( 'top-area-'. $i );
                            echo '';
                        }
                    }*/

                echo '';
            echo '';

            echo ''; // icon-up-open-mini
        echo '';

    }
?>

Comment: Are you using any slider. If yes then post your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hero slider for it.[Hero-slider](https://codyhouse.co/gem/hero-slider/)

You can view demo and download slide from here

Hope you will like it :)

Answer (score 0):

put image inside and anchor tag and write code for click events. 
Alternatively, use href of image on click.